# Is this large bipedal robot real or realizable?

Tags: design

I saw this [link](https://www.instagram.com/p/BOEpUnQjgnb/) today. This robot seems real, but redditors on a reddit [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/robotics/comments/5iwpj6/a_large_bipedal_robot/) argued that it might be CGI. It doesn't seem unfeasible to make such as robot IMO. There isn't anything out of the norm from the video except the size. Plus, there exist Kurata and Megabot, though they don't make bipedal robot, the scale is similar. From roboticist's point view, is this robot real? What are the technological limitation preventing such a robot being developed if it's fake?

Comment: See also http://www.wired.co.uk/article/korea-building-giant-robot-mech

Answer (score 3):

On the video is a 4 meter tall mecha robot which makes heavy noise while walking forward. To determine if this is a real robot or fake, the first step is to enter the name of creator Vitaly Bulgarov into a search engine like Linkedln to find more about him. Linkedln says that Bulgarov works for the gaming-industry and is an artist. So it is normal, that Google Scholar and ResearchGate has no papers from him. From a academic point of view, he doesn't exists. If this is a real robot, it wasn't created by any universities worldwide. From the technical point of view this kind of mechanic is possible. The most advanced university driven project is until now is "SRI DURUS".